# With MyBatis, how can I build an SqlSessionFactory without writing a configuration file (i.e. programmatically)?

Tags: java, annotations, mybatis

I am trying to write a unit test for a DAO implemented using MyBatis using annotations. I would like to instantiate that DAO to unit test against my (in-memory) database. However, the only way I see to instantiate it is through a `SqlSessionFactory` and the only way I see to see instantiate one of those is by using a `SqlSessionFactoryBuilder` only of whose methods that a configuration file.

However, in my unit test I already have a connection to the in-memory database can I just use that to somehow instantiate the mapper? That would also allow me to mock or spy the `Connection` later if I needed to for a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SqlSessionFactory` class has a `openSession(Connection connection)` method. You can use it to retrieve a `SqlSession` using the `Connection` you have to your in memory db.

You can build a `SqlSessionFactory` programmatically without using a configuration file with the following code:

```
Environment environment = new Environment("ID", transactionFactory, dataSource);
Configuration configuration = new Configuration(environment);
configuration.addMappers(mappersPackageName);
// Other configuration tweaks
SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(configuration);
```

Then you can mock or stub the `DataSource` to return your desired `Connection` instance.

Comment: But how do I get an `SqlSessionFactory` instance without having to feed a configuration file to the `SqlSessionFactoryBuilder` ?

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do that. You must have a way to instantiate the `SqlSessionFactory` outside the test: why can't you do the same?

Comment: Because I don't want to reuse that because that file changes all the time and I want to have a separate configuration for unit testing. Since it's only used for unit testing I don't want the hassle of an external file. It also means that I could inject mock objects into the DAOs.

Comment: I updated my answer. However, I'm still not convinced this is a good idea.

Comment: Well, it is an option I want available, and thanks for the edit to fix the typo in my question. This is exactly what I was looking for, but I'll edit to spell out the final step for others who come across. Just so that we are clear: I am only doing this for my unit tests, not production code. There it would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use [junit](https://github.com/kentbeck/junit/wiki) for testing this. Check out [this link](http://blog.idleworx.com/2011/02/part8-idleworx-monster-mybatis-tutorial.html) for more info

The `setup()` method would be the correct point in this case to create a `SqlSessionFactory` object

```
 @BeforeClass
 public static void setUp() throws Exception {
  log.info("starting up myBatis tests");
  String resource = "mybatis.config.xml";
  Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(resource); 
  sf = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader,"testing");
 }
```

Comment: I was asking about doing it without writing a text file, which is what "mybatis.config.xml" would be.